# Mostrar u ocultar un boton despues de una consulta get

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy realizando una consulta de un valor a la base de datos, y si encuentra el valor, me lista los resultados encontrados.

de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y

Listando resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando no hace nada, necesito que me aparezca un botón que ya tengo creado en otra vista

Intente con javascript, pero no lo logre, intente cambiando la función index para que cuando el campo estuviera vacio, me enviara directamente a crear el usuario si no esta, pero como se carga vacio el campo nada que hacer, se me bloquea.

```html
if ($request != null) {
            return view('admin.pacientes.create');
        }else{
        $items = Paciente::documento($request->get('documento'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();

        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('items'));
```

por lo que solo estoy usando esta parte.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $items = Paciente::documento($request->get('documento'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();

        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('items'));

}
```

Pero cuando no encuentra nada, pues no me lista nada.

El botón que necesito que aparezca es este

```
<div class="box-header" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6de;">
          <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route(ADMIN . '.pacientes.create') }}"  title="Agregar Paciente">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></i>
          </a>
          </div>
```

Alguien me podría brindar alguna ayuda, o alguna sugerencia ?

Gracias.

Comment: creo que deberías chequear si $items está vacío y no si $request está vacío. Algo así `if ($items->isEmpty()) { //... }` después de hacer la consulta a BD

Comment: pero en la vista ?,

if ($items!= null) {

Pero no entiendo, en la visa como puedo validarlo, con el codigo que pusiste ?

Comment: Lo intente así y no funciono:

@foreach ($items as $item)
@if($items->isEmpty())
<div class="box-header" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6de;">
          <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route(ADMIN . '.pacientes.create') }}"  title="Agregar Paciente">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></i>
          </a>
          </div>
          else

Comment: puede ser en la vista o en el controlador. Escribí una respuesta con lo que creo es lo que intentas hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con solo Laravel (sin js), viendo lo que has intentado, se me ocurren 2 posibilidades.

En el Controlador, devolviendo otra vista si no devuelve nada la consulta a BD:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $items = Paciente::documento($request->get('documento'))->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate();
    if ($items->isEmpty())
        return view('admin.pacientes.create');

    return view('admin.dashboard', compact('items'));
}
```

O en la vista, agregando el botón si la variable está vacía:

```php
@if ($items->isEmpty())
    <div class="box-header" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6de;">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route(ADMIN . '.pacientes.create') }}"  title="Agregar Paciente">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
@else
    @foreach ($items as $item)
    // ...
    @endforeach
@endif
```

O con @forelse, basado en el comentario de @Aprendiz:

```php
@forelse ($items as $item)
    // ...
@empty
    <div class="box-header" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom:1px solid #d2d6de;">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route(ADMIN . '.pacientes.create') }}"  title="Agregar Paciente">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Efectivamente, con el @if, me funciono a la perfección.

Comment: genial, agregué un @else en la respuesta para el caso en que no esté vacía, basado en lo que comentaste mas arriba.

Comment: Te podría molestar con una ultima cosa? Un alert, para cuando no haya nada, que salga un alert junto con el botón.

Comment: sí, lo mas sencillo sería poner un script dentro del @if: `@if ($items->isEmpty())
    <script> alert("Sin pacientes!!"); </script>
@else`

Comment: También pudieras usar forelse

Comment: cierto, con @forelse te ahorras un par de líneas